# Setting up individually accessible public_html for each user of a linux machine

Tags: linux, website, redhat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting up individually accessible public_html for each user of a linux machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/226112/setting-up-individually-accessible-public-html-for-each-user-of-a-linux-machine)

I have a dedicated server on which I have a site accessible as http://www.example.com

I need to create a user and allow him to access a page such as: http://user.example.com

What do I need to do so that he can access public_html from the internet as http://user.example.com? I want him to be able to execute php scripts as well (which I dont think should be a problem as the website on this site can do it already).

I don't have cPanel. I am running RHEL5/CentOS.

This is a 'duplicate' of [Setting up individually accessible public_html for each user of a linux machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/226112/setting-up-individually-accessible-public-html-for-each-user-of-a-linux-machine) as I didn't get a response there.

Comment: The fact that you don't get an answer when you ask a question in the right place is not a good reason for asking the same question in the wrong place.  This belongs on serverfault.

Comment: @Don - not disagreeing. Please kick it to SF / close this... but can you help with an answer?

Comment: @matt74tm - I can't, as I'm not a moderator.  But if a moderator does, or enough people the right close vote, it'll happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides it's wrong or not to publish this question, I'm not able to do anything more than answer.
Just as a pointer, you must read Apache (or your http server) manual.
In case of apache there you can define virtual hosts where each user can access user.example.com, if they must share the public_html, then you can create symbolic links to the same dir.

Google it: "virtual hosts "
and read about it.

Good luck!