# Creating a public_html for a user on a Red Hat Linux Server

Tags: linux, redhat, httpd, selinux

I'm just trying to make a public_html folder under my username on a Red Hat Linux Server
(and it's all been a bit of a headache).

I made the folder and set the permissions to 755.
I wasn't sure how to deal with Apache (and admittedly finding the httpd.conf file was a nightmare, thanks to an unconventional directory layout), but now I've found it, I'm not sure what to do.

I've seen this question; [Setting up individually accessible public_html for each user of a linux machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/226112/setting-up-individually-accessible-public-html-for-each-user-of-a-linux-machine), but I don't understand the answer. How can I 'use mod_userdir' (I'm quite new to all of this).

I've looked at this;
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html

Am I supposed to append something for the 'httpd..conf file?

I tried appending 'UserDir enabled username' to the top, and restart Apache, but still I can't find a page at;
domain.com/~username/

What could the problem be?
Am I using mod_userdir incorrectly? (I don't even know HOW to use it)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What RedHat version do you have installed? On RedHat 6.x it's pretty straightforward:

1) let's assume I have a user `ec2-user` created with home directory `/home/ec2-user`

2) create a directory `/home/ec2-user/public_html` and make sure that directory `/home/ec2-user` and `/home/ec2-user/public_html` have set permissions at least 0711 (executable bit set on other means that `apache` user under which apache2 web server is running will have permission to enter these directories). Additionally, any content of that directory has to be readable by the `apache` user.

3) enable `UserDir` module in apache2 web server configuration which is available in the file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. Comment out the line `UserDir disabled` and uncomment the line `UserDir public_html`:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    #
    # UserDir is disabled by default since it can confirm the presence
    # of a username on the system (depending on home directory
    # permissions).
    #
    #UserDir disabled

    #
    # To enable requests to /~user/ to serve the user's public_html
    # directory, remove the "UserDir disabled" line above, and uncomment
    # the following line instead:
    #
    UserDir public_html

</IfModule>
```

4) test apache2 web server configuration with `httpd -t`, it should return `Syntax OK` otherwise something went wrong

5) restart apache2 web server with `service httpd restart` and optionally, enable the service with `chkconfig httpd on` on boot

6) finally, if you have selinux enabled in `enforcing` mode - you can check it with `sestatus` - you have to run this command `setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content=on` to allow apache2 web server to read user content

7) test it, e.g. from the server run `w3m http://localhost/~ec2-user`, if there are any errors they should be logged to the log file `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: I hadn't commented out 'UserDir disabled'; you're a lifesaver! :)
(Why is that instruction so difficult to find?!

Comment: @Anti-Earth Once you gain some experience, you will find it logical to search configuration files (to check for things like pre-existing values or useful comments).  Red Hat documents many beginner details like this in their [docs](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Deployment_Guide/index.html#s1-The_Apache_HTTP_Server) and if you have a subscription, in their paid knowledge base.